# Javascript not working as expected in Github's htmlpreview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, github

I have a project in Github (https://github.com/ad-johnson/griddle) which I'm previewing in HTMLPreview (http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/ad-johnson/griddle/blob/master/griddle.html) and for the life of me I can't work out why it works locally on my Mac but not via HTMLPreview.
It's a simple project written in HTML and Javascript using jQuery: basically, use your mouse to colour in squares of a grid.  It's possible to change colours, change grid size and so on. There are 2 problems:

1. When first loading the page, rather than creating a 16x16 grid, it seems to double up so it runs off the bottom of the screen.  Pressing the "new" button draws it correctly.
2. I am intercepting keypress even and toggling pausing the colouring when p is pressed.  This just isn't working at all at the moment so it isn't able to draw - essentially it remains paused.

Ignoring (1) for now, for (2) this is the relevant code:

```
    $(document).keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which==80 || event.which==112) {
        event.preventDefault(); /* don't propogate as it may register in an input box */
        pause();
    }
});

    function pause() {
    if(gridSettings.paused) {
        $('.paused').css({'visibility': 'hidden'}); /* currently paused so un-pause */
    } else {
        $('.paused').css({'visibility': 'visible'});
    }
    gridSettings.paused = !gridSettings.paused;
```

}

```
        <p>Enter the HTML file to preview: <input type="url" id="file" value="" placeholder="e.g. https://github.com/user/repo/blob/master/index.html" size="70"> <input type="submit" value="&raquo;"></p>

        <p>or prepend to the URL: <strong>http://htmlpreview.github.io/?</strong>https://raw.github.com/twbs/bootstrap/gh-pages/2.3.2/index.html</p>

        <p>or use this bookmarklet while browsing GitHub or BitBucket: <a href="javascript:void('http://htmlpreview.github.io/'==window.location?alert('Drag me to your bookmarks bar!'):window.location='http://htmlpreview.github.io/?'+window.location)"><strong>HTMLPreview</strong></a></p>
```

The keypress intercept is within $(document).ready().  function Pause() is outside that block.

I've tried using the debugging tools in Safari.  With a breakpoint on the code line that calls pause(); in the keypress event handler, when I press 'p' it reaches that breakpoint.  However when I step into pause() it doesn't call the function (which has another breakpoint on it), instead it steps to the third line of HTML code (...use this bookmarklet...).

My first thought was maybe a function or global variable is being re-defined by HTMLPreview (I wrote most of this before coming across an article about why globals would be bad!) but I've gone through the code to the extent I can and can't see a conflict.

I'm fairly new to this (if you can't tell) and I'm struggling with working out why it isn't working in HTMLPreview but it's fine running locally.  Can anyone tell me anything about quirks in HTMLPreview or why its run time behaviour is different?  Perhaps give me some debugging pointers?

Comment: Have you looked in the console for errors?

Comment: Yes.  There is an error related to loading favicon, but that's not one of my assets so is presumably something related to htmlpreview.  It doesn't appear to be impacting the execution of html or javascript.  Apart from that, nothing.

Comment: @Mike: actually, I noticed two more errors related to the CSS: console reported that my two CSS files were not parsed because they were the wrong mime type.  Not sure how I fix that - in my HTML I have the type set to 'text/css' but I think this is a function of the web server??

Comment: Sorry to keep posting these additional comments but Chrome is reporting the wrong mime type for CSS and JS; Firefox and Safari are reporting the wrong mime type for css.  In Firefox and Safari, it isn't working (but the page is styled properly); in Chrome it is working (and is styled properly.)  As it is styled properly and it is executing javascript I'm stumped - but at least it works in Chrome.